# Passing empty params as filter condition in flask sqlalchemy get request

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

#### Scenario

I am building a `GET` API which is supposed to take params, apply the filters and return the result.

**Tech-stack:** *flask-restful(framework), flask-sqlalchemy(orm), MySQL(database)*

Suppose I have four params in my `GET` request namely, `p1, p2, p3, p4` and corresponding values be `v1, v2, v3, v4`. Any or all of the params CAN HAVE A NULL VALUE.

***Example:*** This `http://myhost.com/apply-filter?p1=v1&p3=v4` is a valid request for our case.

Assume that same fields(columns) are present in the database table as well.
The model name is `Model`

#### What's not the problem

The API ought to apply `and` condition for all these params and return all the rows which satisfy these params. I know a bit of flask and sqlalchemy so, at first, I did something like this:

```
db.session.query(Model).filter(Model.p1 == v1, Model.p2 == v2, Model.p3 == v3, Model.p4 == v4).all()
```

Works fine...

#### Problem

Now the problem is, I can't figure out what to do if the user-request does not have values for one or more parameters, ***i.e.** what if she/he wants to filter according to only p1 and p3*?

I know I can solve this problem using `if...else`, but **is there a better way**?

**Something like:**

```
db.session.query(Model).filter(Model.p1 == v1 or all, Model.p2 == v2 or all, Model.p3 == v3 or all, Model.p4 == v4 or all)
```

> Request method: GET
> Assume only one table.
> Fetching the params using `request.args.get('param')`

Namaste

Answer (score 2):

## Method 1 (Backend)

You can do this in a more elegant way than `if...else` but not necessarily simpler. Let's suppose this is your request url:

```
http://myhost.com/apply-filter?p1=v1&p2=&p3=v3
```

As you can see the value of p2 is empty. You will have first to get the dictionary of the arguments/values.

```
args = request.args #args = {"p1": v1, "p2": None, "p3": v3}
```

Next, you will need to filter this dictionary in order to remove items that have a None value.

```
filtered_args = {k: v for k, v in args.items() if v is not None} #filtered_args = {"p1": v1, "p3": v3}
```

You will also have to build a consumable Sqlalchelmy filter (BinaryExpression):

```
filters = [getattr(Model, attribute) == value for attribute, value in filtered_args.items()]
```

Finally, you can make your query using the **and_** conjuction:

```
db.session.query(Model).filter(and_(*filters)).all()
```

## Method 2 (Frontend)

You can also filter the request on frontend before making api request. This can be done by originally not including parameters with empty values. Otherwise, you will have to use some basic Javascript code in order to remove unnecessary parameters ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete))

```
let url = new URL('https://example.com?foo=1&bar=2&foo=3');
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

// Delete the foo parameter.
params.delete('foo'); //Query string is now: 'bar=2'
```